# PNG24(透過) と PNG8（アルファチャネル）について

Tags: 画像

**Q1.PNG24について**
PNG24：24ビットカラー
PNG32：24ビットカラー＋8ビットアルファチャンネル
と思っていたのですが、下記はどういう意味ですか？

> png24
>    [png8同様に情報がない部分は透過処理が可能](http://create-pleasures.com/png)

- 24ビットカラー内(使用していない部分)にアルファチャンネルが含まれる。
  透明度%指定できる
- 24ビットカラー内(使用していない部分)に透過が含まれる。
  透明度%指定できない
- アルファチャンネルつきPNG-24の意味

---

**Q2.PNG8について**

> [PNG8（アルファチャネル）](https://iwb.jp/png8-png24-png32-analyze/)

どういう意味ですか？

- 8ビットカラー内(使用していない部分)にアルファチャンネルが含まれる。
  透明度%指定できる
- アルファチャンネルつきPNG-8の意味

---

**Q3.そもそも**

- 24ビットカラー＋8ビットアルファチャンネル を何と呼ぶ？

> [24bitカラーにαチャネル8bitを加えたものを32bitカラーとは呼ばない](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/407626)

---

＜ 追記 ＞
下記認識で合っていますか？

- **alphaチャンネルがある場合**
  透明度%指定できる
  何色でも(半)透明にできる
- **alphaチャンネルがない場合**
  透明度%指定できない
  何色透明にできるかはPNGのカラータイプによって異なる
  ※tRNSチャンクで透過色を指定する

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Q1.PNG24について**
> PNG24：24ビットカラー
> PNG32：24ビットカラー＋8ビットアルファチャンネル

**慣例的には** 上記の通りの解釈です。[PNG公式サイトFAQ](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/pngfaq.html#png8-png24)より部分引用します：

> Q. What are "PNG8" and "PNG24"?
> A. *PNG24*, on the other hand, is shorthand for "24-bit PNG" and refers to truecolor or RGB (red/green/blue) images. Each pixel in such images is 24 bits (3 bytes) deep and directly specifies a color instead of acting as an index into a lookup table of colors (i.e., a palette). [...]
>
> [...] However, when tools occasionally mention *PNG32*, they are invariably referring to 32-bit RGB+alpha (RGBA), not 32-bit gray+alpha. [...]

言及先サイトの説明は、かなり簡略化された（もしくは無理解による誤った）説明になっているようです。

> 24ビットカラー内(使用していない部分)にアルファチャンネルが含まれる。透明度%指定できる
> 24ビットカラー内(使用していない部分)に透過が含まれる。透明度%指定できない

24ビットカラー＝8bit-Truecolour（`IHDR`チャンクColourType=2）と仮定した場合、`tRNS`チャンクで"透明色"を1つだけ指定できます。透明度は100%固定です。

> アルファチャンネルつきPNG-24の意味

おそらく 8bit-Truecolour＋透明色指定 のことを指すと考えられます。この場合、任意の透明度指定ではなく、透明色を1つ指定できるだけです。

---

> **Q2.PNG8について**
> PNG8（アルファチャネル）
> どういう意味ですか？
> アルファチャンネルつきPNG-8の意味

PNG仕様上は直接対応するものが存在しませんが、8bit-IndexedColour（`IHDR`チャンクColorType=3）＋`tRNS`チャンクによる透過パレット指定 を指す可能性が高いです。

> 8ビットカラー内(使用していない部分)にアルファチャンネルが含まれる。透明度%指定できる

概ね実現可能です。`tRNS`チャンクで透過パレットを指定する際、その[パレットインデックスがアルファ値として扱われ](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/iso/index-object.html#11tRNS)ます。

---

> **Q3.そもそも**
> 24ビットカラー＋8ビットアルファチャンネル を何と呼ぶ？
> 24bitカラーにαチャネル8bitを加えたものを32bitカラーとは呼ばない

（個人の主義主張はさておき）PNG公式サイトFAQによれば、PNG32＝「24ビットカラー＋8ビットアルファチャンネル」を指すことが一般的のようです。

---

**追記への回答**

> 下記認識で合っていますか？
>
> alphaチャンネルがある場合
> 透明度%指定できる
> 何色でも(半)透明にできる

正しい認識です。

> alphaチャンネルがない場合
> 透明度%指定できない
> 何色透明にできるかはPNGのカラータイプによって異なる
> ※tRNSチャンクで透過色を指定する

一部不正確です。場合分けをすると下記の通りです：

- Alphaチャネル無しGrayscale：ある1色(Gray値)を透明色(alpha=0)として指定できます。
- Alphaチャネル無しTruecolour（RGB）：ある1色(RGB値)を透明色(alpha=0)として指定できます。
- Alphaチャネル無しIndexedColour（パレット方式）：複数のパレットインデックスを指定できます。パレットインデックス値そのものがalpha値として扱われるため、例えばパレットインデックス=128を指定すると透明度50%として扱えます。

Comment: 「tRNSチャンク」という言葉を初めて知りました。疑問点を本文に追記しました

Comment: チャンクに関しては、少し説明が唐突過ぎましたね。PNG形式データは内部的に["チャンク(chunk)"](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/iso/index-object.html#4Concepts.FormatChunks)と呼ばれる構造化されたブロックの集合として表現されます。`tRNS`チャンクもその一種で、透明度(Transparency)を表すデータブロックです。

Comment: 「パレットインデックス値そのものがalpha値として扱われるため、例えばパレットインデックス=128を指定すると透明度50%」。128/256で50%というわけですね。内容を完全に勘違いしていました。大変参考になりました

Answer (score 5):

そもそもPNG8 / PNG24 / PNG32というのは正式な用語ではありません。ですので何を指すのかは筆者にしかわかりませんし、各々の筆者が同じものを指している保証がありません。

その上で、[PNGは仕様として次の種類のみ](https://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-PNG-20031110/#table111)がサポートされています。

- Greyscale; 1, 2, 4, 8, 16bit
- Truecolour; 8, 16bit
- Indexed-colour; 1, 2, 4, 8bit
- Greyscale with alpha; 8, 16bit
- Truecolour with alpha; 8, 16bit

alphaをサポートしない上３つに対しては透過色を指定できます。指定された色はその色が表示されるわけではなく透過します。

---

#### A1.

よくわかりませんが、透過色のことを語ろうとしているのかもしれません。

#### A2.

よくわかりませんが、少なくとも仕様上存在しない形式です。

#### A3.

どう呼ぶかは個人の主義・好みで決まります。筆者が32bitで表現される他の色表現を知っているために、24ビットカラー＋8ビットアルファチャンネルのことを32bitカラーと呼びたくないと主張されたのかもしれません。

Comment: 「Truecolour; 8, 16bit」と書いてあるので、PNGの最大ビット数は32ではなく(16×3=)48ですか？

Comment: 仕様上はTruecolour with alphaの16bit＝64bitが上限値ですね。アルファチャネルを計上しない流儀であれば、16bit×3＝48bitとも言えます。

Comment: なるほど、アルファチャネルを見落としていました。